Science-fiction short story based on Balaam and his donkey
The biblical story of Balaam and his donkey has Balaam riding on his donkey to curse the Israelites but the donkey balks and Balaam reconsiders his intention.
I'm looking for a unmemorable short story in which someone is being driven to perform an action that I can't remember. His driver suffers a spot of catatonia and the protagonist is forced to reconsider and changes his mind. The action may take place on the moon, but I was wrong last time when I placed a different story there so I'm probably wrong again.
It's a short story, probably from the seventies.

Anthony Boucher wrote a story called Balaam (1954)
It takes place on Mars, and a chaplain has been asked to curse the alien invaders. He considers doing so, but in the end blesses them instead, as they can live on Mars without spacesuits or masks, so it is more naturally theirs than ours.
At the end the narrator recalls that in the Bible, Balaam is killed by the invaders he has blessed, but reflects that no one knows what became of the ass, with whom he identifies.
The story was published in Raymond J Healy Nine Tales of Space and Time, and probably elsewhere.

And probably elsewhere.. what have you got against the ISFDB?

Nothing in particular, but the Healy anthology is where I discovered this story, so that's what I cited.

It seems Boucher really liked the Balaam imagery.

This is very likely to be the story I read but I can't be certain without seeing it. and I might not be certain even then, so I'll accept it. Thanks to all.

It's available from the Internet Archive in Isaac Asimov Presents The Great SF Stories #16, https://archive.org/details/greatsfstories160000asim/page/316/mode/2up

This somewhat matches (with a few differences) the short story The Quest for Saint Aquin by Anthony Boucher, first published in 1951.
The story is set on Earth approximately one thousand years in the future. Catholicism has been driven underground, with "crypto-priests" being led by a "crypto-pope".
From the wikipedia summary:

The central character is a crypto-priest named Thomas who is charged
by the crypto-pope with finding and reporting on the final resting
place of a semi-legendary figure called Aquin... Thomas is provided
with an intelligent multi-terrain transport vehicle called a robass
("robotic ass"), to assist him in locating and visiting Aquin's tomb.
To Thomas's surprise, this robot can talk and is theologically
literate. It cynically tries to persuade him, for example, to abandon
his quest since he had not been asked to find Aquin, but rather to
report that he had so that the Pope can begin the process of
canonization.

In the end, after long arguments with his robass, Thomas does find Aquin's tomb but discovers

 that he was actually a robot, so the legends of the incorruptability of his flesh were true, but only in a trivial sense.


The Space Pope?

Now that the Internet Archive is back, the story can be read here or (with free registration) here.

Two for the price of one, cool!
